# Could not get data from fifo

Tags: bash, fifo

I'm working with pipe such way (bash script). I write in one pipe `$server` and read from another pipe `$serverPID`. This is client sample code:

```
echo "Get var"
mkfifo "${server}$$"
echo "$$ 2" > $server
read var <  "${server}$$"
echo "var: ${var}"
```

This is server sample code:

```
int fd;
if ((fd = open(fifo, O_RDWR)) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open fifo");
}

ssize_t written;

written = write(fd, buf, strlen(buf));
if (written == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not write into fifo");                        
}
printf("written %d into %s\n", written, fifo);
```

I see that all data was written succesfully, but I get waiting on client side without appearing written data. Where is the problem?

Comment: I add '&' in client but get no result. I get result if I terminate server only

Comment: You're writing to a file in the client, not the fifo. Did you mean `echo "$$ 2" > "$server$$"`?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `close(fd)` solved the problem

Comment: You could also do `fflush(fifo)`.